# Configuring Jetty to access a pool of shared objects

Tags: java, jetty, object-pooling

I have an object that processes text in a stateless way. It basically takes some input and returns the result. However, creating the object is expensive, as it needs to load a lot of data into memory. I would like to build a web service around it using Jetty, so that I can parse text from external sources. Jetty should keep a pool of such objects in memory and use them to process the HTTP requests (making sure that a single object is being used by only one HTTP thread at a time). How can I configure the server to do it?

Comment: If it's stateless, why not just use a single shared instance? It should be thread-safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jetty by itself is not going to help a lot on this, but you can easily plug the [pool component of Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/pool/) to achieve what you want.

Then. from your web service, you can just reference this object pool to get your processing object.

Comment: How does it work? I mean the interface seems pretty simple, but how do I integrate the object pool into my web application? Does it run as a separate process, or as a separate thread managed by Jetty?

Comment: It depends on the framework for your webapp. In a simple way, you can make this object static and make it thread safe. In a more subtle way you could use JNDI. (http://humblecode.blogspot.com/2009/05/gwt-16-using-jndi-datasource.html)